# Structure for your go workspace when using private git repository

Tags: go

Ive been trying to work out what the standard folder layout/structure for go code/workspaces when you are not using github.

I can see how  `go get` works when fetching github projects, but assumedly my own git projects would not have the `{github.com}/{username}/{projectname}` structure that is referenced by `go get` and how is structed on disk after you do `go get`

What layout and `git get` url should you have when using your own git private repositories?

Comment: I've tried to find this info on various go sites, but none of them seem to go into real world detail. (ie mix of github and your own repositories)

Comment: If you do not intend to open source it or make it "go get"-able you can do whatever you like e.g. `$GOPATH/src/dev/null/hubbabubba/1/3/8/my/strange/www.google.com/package/name`.

Comment: Cool, I guess I am asking what do you do if you do want it `go get`able?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package in itself carries no reference to where it is stored. You only have:

```
package mypackage
```

So, you can have your local version in your own structure, as Volker pointed out in his comment. This is the import path you use in your own projects:

```
import "my/custom/path/mypackage"
```

Then you can open source it and put `mypackage` onto GitHub. This will allow everyone else to get it with the `go get` command, but they will be using the `github.com` import:

```
import "github.com/myuser/mypackage"
```

This works perfectly fine **unless you want to open-source packages which imports `my/custom/path/mypackage`**. In such a case, you should consider restructuring your paths so that you use the same github import paths as the users of your package does.

Answer (score 3):

From `go help importpath`:

> For code hosted on other servers, import paths may either be qualified
>   with the version control type, or the go tool can dynamically fetch
>   the import path over https/http and discover where the code resides
>   from a  tag in the HTML.
>
> To declare the code location, an import path of the form
>
> repository.vcs/path
>
> specifies the given repository, with or without the .vcs suffix, using
>   the named version control system, and then the path inside that
>   repository.  The supported version control systems are:
>
> Bazaar      .bzr    Git         .git    Mercurial   .hg     Subversion  .svn

Then I belive you can setup your own git server with [GitLab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq) or [GoGits](http://gogits.org/), then your import path will be your server domain.

But If you have a private repo with github or bitbucket, your package will go-get-able. Just run a  normal "go get" and you will asked to enter your password.

Answer (score 1):

For unknown repo hosting sites, `go get` fetches the HTTP/HTTPS url first and checks if it has a meta tag linking to the git/hg/bzr repo.

See ["Remote import paths"](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths).