# golang "go get comand" how this works?

Tags: go

Initially I thought it works as like java maven
where it has its own repository and downloads dependencies

but go git seems to have dependency with git Bazaar like version control system.

```
go get launchpad.net/mgo 
go: missing Bazaar command. See http://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package launchpad.net/mgo: exec: "bzr": executable file not found in $PATH
```

**Edit:**
My main problem is when i do

go get gopkg.in/mgo.v2   I get

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gopkg.in/mgo.v2/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
package gopkg.in/mgo.v2: exit status 128
```

This is because of git needs certificate. I am able to  `clone this repo using

git -c http.sslVerify=false clone`

I have to do the similar setting some where to get it from go get command

Comment: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies

Comment: I have edited my answer to address your edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My main problem is when I do:

```
go get gopkg.in/mgo.v2

fatal: unable to access 'https://gopkg.in/mgo.v2/': 
SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
package gopkg.in/mgo.v2: exit status 128
```

If the underlying repo is a Git repo (which seems to be the case here: [github.com/go-mgo/mgo/tree/v2](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/tree/v2)), then you can deactivate ssl (temporarily) with:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

---

Initial answer:

As mentioned in [go remote import path](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths), some pre-defined import path will require some associated version control tool to be present:

Launchpad (Bazaar)

```
import "launchpad.net/project"
```

Go can get from any repo you want, but, as explained in "[Structure for your go workspace when using private git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23808985/6309)"

> import paths may either be qualified with the version control type, or the go tool can dynamically fetch the import path over https/http and discover where the code resides from a tag in the HTML.

Here, the import path is enough for go to infer what tool it needs.